# Resources for an Oracle beginner

Tags: oracle, ibm-midrange

Can anyone recommend some good resources that highlight the differences between Oracle and the AS/400 database?

I am trying to help someone with a lot of AS/400 experience implement an Oracle installation, and they need some guidance.

A book or online resource would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this a fair few times and the solutions out there really depend on the environment (enterprise / mission critical or development).  The BEST way would be the ***Oracle AS/400 Gateway***.  Here are some important links in that area:

Allow AS/400 apps to access oracle with the Oracle Access Manager:
[Installation Guide for the AS/400 Oracle Access Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B13951_01/toc.htm)

Allow your Oracle apps to access AS/400 tables and be queried using Oracle:
[Oracle Transparent Gateway for DB/2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B13983_01/toc.htm)

^^^Those products are fairly expensive but super powerful.^^^

Alternately, here are some more academic approaches to the situation:

Here's a technical comparison of the two technologies... It's a little propagandaish*.
[Technical comparisons of Oracle and DB/2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cgisecurity.com%2Fdatabase%2Foracle%2Fpdf%2FCWP_9IVSDB_SECURITY.PDF&ei=RSuvSLSRDI6usAPE-Yht&usg=AFQjCNFNFGPT9WjTOibt5AmK7oQwTIq_Cg&sig2=34iBQyH401KRnKGQ8sSlKg)

Here's a document written from the opposite point of view - Someone moving from Oracle to DB2.  I still find it's useful information:
[Leverage your Oracle 10g skills to learn DB2...](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/dm-0401gupta/)

And another IBM link that has some really great information all around:
[IBM Developer Network Search Results](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/search/searchResults.jsp?searchType=1&pageLang=&displaySearchScope=dW&searchSite=dW&lastUserQuery1=oracle+db2+differences&lastUserQuery2=&lastUserQuery3=&lastUserQuery4=&qa=oracle%2520db2%2520differences&query=oracle+db2+&searchScope=dW&Go.x=0&Go.y=0)

Hope this helps!

*Yes, I know propagandaish is not a real word.

Answer (score 0):

These links are not AS/400 specific, but generally a good place starting with Oracle:

http://tahiti.oracle.com
http://asktom.oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

Simple Talk Publishing have just set up http://www.oracleoverflow.com/, which is a dedicated Stack Exchange site. You could try posting your questions there?